# Does dask S3 reading cache the data on disk/RAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dask

I've been reading about dask and how it can read data from S3 and do processing from that in a way that does not need the data to completely reside in RAM.

I want to understand what `dask` would do if I have a very large S3 file what I am trying to read. Would it:

- Load that S3 file into RAM ?
- Load that S3 file and cache it in `/tmp` or something ?
- Make multiple calls to the S3 file in parts

I am assuming here I am doing a lot of different complicated computations on the dataframe and it may need multiple passes on the data - i.e. let's say a join, group by, etc.

Also, a side question is if I am doing a select from S3 > join > groupby > filter > join - would the temporary dataframes which I am joining with be on S3 ? or on disk ? or RAM ?

I know Spark uses RAM and overflows to HDFS for such cases.

I'm mainly thinking of single machine dask at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

For many file-types, e.g., CSV, parquet, the original large files on S3 can be safely split into chunks for processing. In that case, each Dask task will work on one chunk of the data at a time by making separate calls to S3. Each chunk will be in the memory of a worker while it is processing it.

When doing a computation that involves joining data from many file-chunks, preprocessing of the chunks still happens as above, but now Dask keeps temporary structures around to accumulate partial results. How much memory will depend on the chunking size of the data, which you may or may not control, depending on the data format, and exactly what computation you want to apply to it.

Yes, Dask is able to spill to disc in the case that memory usage is large. This is better handled in the distributed scheduler (which is now the recommended default even on a single machine). Use the `--memory-limit` and `--local-directory` CLI arguments, or their equivalents if using the `Client()`/`LocalCluster()`, to control how much memory each worker can use and where temporary files get put.